# ClassCastException while I use custom classloader

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, classcastexception, dynamic-class-loaders

I try to understand java clasloading. I wrote example:

```
class XLoader extends ClassLoader {

    // карта отображения имен классов на файлы .class, где хранятся их определения
    HashMap<String, String> mappings;

    XLoader(HashMap mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }


    public synchronized Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            // важно!
            // приоритет отдан именно загрузке с помощью встроенного загрузчика

            if (!mappings.containsKey(name)) {
                System.out.println("loadClass (" + name + ") with parent classloader");
                return super.findSystemClass(name);
            }
            System.out.println("loadClass (" + name + ") with XLoader");
            String fileName = mappings.get(name);
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            byte[] bbuf = new byte[(int) (new File(fileName).length())];
            fin.read(bbuf);
            fin.close();
            return defineClass(name, bbuf, 0, bbuf.length);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

also I have interface:

```
public interface ISexyInterface {

    public void makeBar ();

}
```

and class:

```
public class SexyClassForLoader implements ISexyInterface {
  ...
}
```

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap();
        mappings.put("sur.che.SexyClassForLoader", "D:\\java_things\\custom-classloader\\out\\production\\custom-classloader1\\sur\\che\\SexyClassForLoader.class");
        // if comment this line you will see
        //mappings.put("sur.che.ISexyInterface", "D:\\java_things\\custom-classloader\\out\\production\\custom-classloader1\\sur\\che\\ISexyInterface.class");

        XLoader xloa = new XLoader(mappings);
        Class sexy_cla = xloa.loadClass("sur.che.SexyClassForLoader");
        System.out.println("class was loaded with " + sexy_cla.getClassLoader());

        Object sexy_ob = sexy_cla.newInstance();
        System.out.println(sexy_ob.getClass().getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(ISexyInterface.class.getClassLoader());
        Thread.sleep(100);
        ISexyInterface local_sexy = (ISexyInterface) sexy_ob;
        local_sexy.makeBar();
    }
```

this example works fine and produces following output:

```
loadClass (sur.che.SexyClassForLoader) with XLoader
loadClass (sur.che.ISexyInterface) with parent classloader
loadClass (java.lang.Object) with parent classloader
class was loaded with sur.che.XLoader@7f31245a
loadClass (java.lang.System) with parent classloader
loadClass (java.io.PrintStream) with parent classloader
SexyClassForLoader$$static
SexyClassForLoader$$init
sur.che.XLoader@7f31245a
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@232204a1
make bar
```

But lets play with:

```
    //mappings.put("sur.che.ISexyInterface", "D:\\java_things\\custom-classloader\\out\\production\\custom-classloader1\\sur\\che\\ISexyInterface.class");
```

If uncomment this line I see following output:

```
loadClass (sur.che.SexyClassForLoader) with XLoader
loadClass (sur.che.ISexyInterface) with XLoader
loadClass (java.lang.Object) with parent classloader
class was loaded with sur.che.XLoader@7f31245a
loadClass (java.lang.System) with parent classloader
loadClass (java.io.PrintStream) with parent classloader
SexyClassForLoader$$static
SexyClassForLoader$$init
sur.che.XLoader@7f31245a
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@232204a1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sur.che.SexyClassForLoader cannot be cast to sur.che.ISexyInterface
    at sur.che.Loader.main(Loader.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Please, explain this behaviour.

### P.S.

I understand that if same class loaded with 2 different loaders. It counted as 2 different classses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If uncomment this line I see following output:......

```
Class sexy_cla = xloa.loadClass("sur.che.SexyClassForLoader");
```

*sur.che.SexyClassForLoader* was loaded by *Xloader* and because it has an interface *sur.che.ISexyInterface* then *jvm* will use the *classloader* of *sur.che.SexyClassForLoader* to load this interface.

But as for this statement:

```
System.out.println(ISexyInterface.class.getClassLoader());
```

because the *class* which contained *main method* was loaded by *AppLoader* So jvm will use *AppLoader* to load *ISexyInterface.class*.

```
 ISexyInterface local_sexy = (ISexyInterface) sexy_ob;
```

And obviously, the classLoader of this ISexyInterface is *AppLoader*, however the inner dependence (*ISexyInterface*) of *SexyClassForLoader* was loaded by *xLoader*. In other words, there are **two** *ISexyInterface.class* in *jvm* one loaded by *Xloader* another by *App*. And the *sexy_ob* implements the *ISexyInterface.class* loaded by **Xloader**. You try to convert *sexy_ob* into a *ISexyInterface type*(loaded by **App**). 
so *castException*.

If commented, there is only one *ISexyInterface .class* which loaded by **App** . So everything is ok.